# Calling data from server using retrofit on login screen and want show data on other activity

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2, getter-setter

I am using retrofit library
I want to call all data on login screen and if login successful then show data in next activity through same getter setter.
Is this possible?

```
public void onResponse(Call<TaskResponse> call, Response<TaskResponse> response) 
{
    int statusCode = response.code();
    String checking = String.valueOf(response.body().getCode());
    if (checking.equals("0"))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid username or Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else if (checking.equals("2"))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Company Code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else if (checking.equals("1")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        List<Task> test;
        test = new ArrayList<Task>();
        test = response.body().getTasks();

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EmpTaskActivity.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) test);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

   //  recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? It is possible, right, and very differents ways (AsyncTask, EventBus, Thread...) but we have no information how you are doing this.

Comment: Yes , it's possible. Send the response to another activity using intent extras

Comment: when we use setter getter with retrofit call, the same setter gatter in other activity ? is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: please check code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the login success (In your LoginActivity).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("DESIRE_KEY",loginModelUsedToCallRetrofitAPI);
startActivity(intent);
```

And at the MainActivity (the second activity you want to call after successful login)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
LoginModelUsedToCallRetrofitAPI loginModelUsedToCallRetrofitAPI = intent.getSerializableExtra("DESIRE_KEY");
```

This should do what you want!

Comment: can you explain what you actually did?

Comment: @SurajKumar On success of the login API you get your model(I have named it LoginModelUsedToCallRetrofitAPI). Than you can pass on that model to the next activity (MainActivity in my case).

Comment: and how to use in Main Activity?

Comment: actually i want to use in recyclerview

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EmpTaskActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("DESIRE_KEY", Task.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();
        List<Task> t = (List<Task>) intent.getSerializableExtra("DESIRE_KEY");

Comment: Actually not! You need to pass the `Task` object not `Task.class` from the login screen.

Comment: O i am trying to do this

Comment: and THANK YOU so much

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem!

Comment: List<Task> test;
                            test = new ArrayList<Task>();
                            test = response.body().getTasks();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EmpTaskActivity.class);
                            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) test);
                            startActivity(intent);

Comment: basically i want this but it crash in every way

Comment: please try to run it

Comment: I can not tell from these lines of codes in your comments. I suggest you to post another question with code which illustrates your problem very clearly.